# PHP script times, regardless of `set_time_limit(0);`

Tags: php, api, timeout

I've got a PHP script using the API of another site and because of the number of requests being extensive, I get a timeout.

My script should take ~2 hours to execute, I have tried to prepend:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
```

but this doesn't work out, the page still times out.

What could cause this?

Comment: Are you using Cloudflare?

Comment: Not that I know of. What is Cloudflare? This is just PHP script sending an API to a company we deal with.

Comment: That is a service, that I know could have caused the error.

Comment: Oh. OK. No, I dont use it. Thanks for the edit too.

Comment: Maybe You didn't understand what @TimSpeckhals is saying. Maybe the API response will respond with an error so the time limit will not work. Did you try to `catch` the error you are getting, so you can show it to us?

Comment: Hi. No errors on the API. I have checked that and all ok that side. I asked the developers who made the API and there is unlimited calls available from their side. This times out after a few minutes all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a work around on this one. May be a little messy, but it works.

I performed 20 API calls to go under the timeout range. Then I used $_SESSION counting and page refresh to create the number of API calls I required.

This means the page never times out.